# Google Play Services - Proguard - We found Ad SDKs in your application

Tags: android, ant, admob, google-play-services, android-proguard

My question is in regards to Google Play's new declaration of ad status and the fact that our application's are being flagged as containing the AdMob SDK (which is included in Google Play Services).

Our apps include Google Play Services (library project) and are built using the Android SDK and Ant (NOT gradle) and have proguard enabled. While proguard appears to be stripping some AdMob items (from looking at Usage.txt), it doesn't appear to be stripping everything which results in Google Play's detection.

I've been analyzing our build scripts and searching for days for something that I may have missed. Basically I'm asking if it's possible to strip AdMob from our apps using Proguard. At this point, I'm thinking it's impossible. If it is indeed impossible, confirming that would also be helpful.

And yes, I do understand that it's possible to include/exclude portions of Google Play Services using Gradle, and we are in the process of migrating our large complex projects, however that process won't be completed for a while. I also understand that as long as your app doesn't contain ads, selecting 'No' shouldn't be a problem, however I would still prefer to fix the issue if possible.

Comment: How your application was flagged? I mean i thought that developer is declaring that fact not any automatic process

Comment: What I meant was that when we declare it as not containing ads, it is stating that our app contains the AdMob SDK. The app does not contain any code to show any ads, but does include Google Play Services. My assumption was that Proguard would have stripped it, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can just include only those portions of the Google Play Services library that you require, even in Ant. Just choose those jars/aars instead of the entire GPS lib.